# TableAdapter List params for IN clause

Tags: sql-server, winforms, tableadapter

SQL Server, VS 2019 Winforms, ReportViewer.

This doesn't work in straight SQL either, so I'll start there.
I have a query that looks like this:

```
declare @d1 Date, @d2 date, @SalesRep nvarchar(20), @customer nvarchar(300), @stype nvarchar(10)
    
    set @d1 = '01 oct 2021'
    set @d2 = getdate()
    set @SalesRep = ''
    set @customer = ''''',''A'',''B'',''C'',''D'',''E'',''F'',''G'',''H'',''I'''
    set @sType=null
    
    select @customer
    
    select 
        vss.Customer, vss.Invoice_No, vss.Salesman, 
        vss.Invoice_Date, vss.Total_Amount, vss.Description 
    from 
        v_SaleSum vss
    where 
        vss.Invoice_Date between @d1 and @d2
        and ((ISNULL(@SalesRep,'') = '') OR (vss.Salesman = @SalesRep))
        **and (Customer in (@customer))**
        and [dbo].[Invoice_sType] (vss.Invoice_No, @sType)=1
    Order by 
        vss.Invoice_No
```

You can see the crux of the issue here.
The @customer param needs to be a list.  But if you comma separate it, as I have the query looks for customers that match the whole comma separated list as one string, not as a list of strings.

I do not have the option of modifying the SQL at runtime because of the whole Dataset, BindingSource, TableAdapter setup.

What am I missing here?  There must be some way to add a list of values to a parameter.

--Update:
Here's why I can't use Table-Value Parameters:
[image: DbTypes for Datasets]
There is no "Table" parameter type supported.

Comment: You can use [Table-Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

Comment: If you want to pass an "array" of IDs as a single string parameter, then you will need to split those values into a table using `STRING_SPLIT()`. That will work in a tsql sense but not particularly optimal. A TVP is a better option.

Comment: Here's the problem using that from a C# dataset perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I could do this:

```
... and (@customer like ('%'''+ Customer+'''%'))
```

Since the match string is in the format '''A'',''B''' (or more simply without having to escape the tick marks, ' 'A','B' '

searching for the customer name to exist in the parameter seems kind of backwards, but its working.

This way, I check if %'A'% is like 'A','B','C'